# firebase permission error when creating a new user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to ensure security in my firebase database. My issue is in restricting user profiles so that only a user may edit his/her own node. When a user signs up, I create a firebase auth user, and immediately add this user to my database with an email; however, I am getting a permission denied error when trying to add to the database a new user.

I am baffled because my simulations in the firebase simulator run smoothly; however, my code does not work as expected. In debugging I tried printing the current uid at the time of writing to the database and comparing that with the authID of the user, and they match. In another step, I simplified the rule to be: `auth != null`, and it failed this as well. This led me to believe the user wasn't being authenticated in time, but the print of the current uid wouldn't work if that were the case.

Here are my rules:

```
"users" : {
    "$user_id": {
        ".read":"true",
        ".write":"auth != null",
        ".validate": "newData.exists()",
        "isAdmin": {
          ".validate":"false"
        },
        "email": {
          ".validate":"newData.val().matches(/^.+@.+\\..+$/)"
        }
     }
}
```

Here is a picture of my chrome inspector console to show the error and the printing of the uid before the error:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to write:

```
    var firstName =         $(".signUpForm #firstName").val();
    var lastName =          $(".signUpForm #lastName").val();
    var emailInput =        $("#emailInput").val();
    var password =          $("#passwordInput").val();
    var passwordConfirm =   $(".signUpForm #passwordConfirmInput").val();

    const promise = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput, password).then(function(user) {
        console.log(user.uid);

        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

       // user signed in
        var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        usersRef.child(uid).set({
            email: emailInput
        }).catch(function(error) {
            displayErrorMessage(error.code);
        }).then(function() {
            //window.location.reload(true);         
        })   
        // $(".logInMessage").html('SignedUp!');
        // $(".logInMessage").css("color", "green");

    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            $(".logInMessage").html('Wrong password.');
            $(".logInMessage").css("color", "red");

        } else {
            $(".logInMessage").css("color", "red");                                 
            $(".logInMessage").html(errorMessage);  
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Restricting a user so they can only edit their own node can be done with the following:

```
".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
```

For the rest of your problems with write access, you'll probably need to experiment in the simulator or try removing some of the rules and reducing scope until you can isolate the offending line.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i was taking it one step at a time. I changed the write rule to only restrict to authenticated users because not even that rule was passed. It seemed like extra work to jump to the second part without it first passing the authentication rule. Also, like i said, unfortunately (or fortunately), the simulator is working just fine and I am able to write as I please. The problem lies in the client side code from that evidence I think.